# MySQL - surrounding precomputed variable with single-quotes prior to inserting

Tags: mysql, sql

The primary key of my table is a char of fixed length 11.

I have precomputed the key in my script, just like this:

`SET pes = LPAD(person_number, 11, '0');`

Now, my variable meets my critera. It only needs to be added to the database.

`INSERT INTO db VALUES(pes, ...);`

This is where my problem arises - since the primary key is supposed to be a char, I need to put the value of my variable in single quotes.

However, I don't know how to do that.
I tried to escape them, but

`'\''pes'\''`

doesn't work.

Is there a simple way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be a problem !

The `mySql` varchar data-type should accept numbers!

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (USER_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
                    USER_NAME VARCHAR(255));
SET @U_ID = LPAD(2018, 11, '0');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (@U_ID, 'USER_1'),(2, 'USER_2');

SELECT * FROM USERS;
```

Will output :

```
USER_ID      |  USER_NAME
-------------------------
00000002018  |  USER_1
2            |  USER_2
```

This is a working [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/enFLhEZpZFfLaKUAvjoyKN/0)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it does work. The funny fact is that the problem that prevented me from inserting my data was a trigger, but that's kinda shameful:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use multi-single-quotes with `concat` function.

```
INSERT INTO db VALUES(concat('''', @pes,''''), ...);
```

Here is a sample

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(col varchar(50));

SET @pes = '1234';                


INSERT INTO T VALUES (concat('''', @pes,''''));
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select col
FROM T;

| col    |
| ------ |
| '1234' |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hVei3aMDvpyAKsU2PAesza/1)

Comment: `concat('', pes,'')` seems to concatenate the value of the variable with two empty strings.

Comment: @LaTeXEnthusiast I edit it you four  single-quotes :)

Comment: I have experimented a little bit and I found a working solution: 
`SELECT concat('\'',pes,'\'');`